# Python / Pandas Large Dataset : Does a row contain an item from a LONG list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe (11k rows) with a column that contains a complex text string ex: "foo bar foobar 2019" or "foo+bar+foobar 2019".

I have another long list (~200) of possible matching strings, ex :
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

I am trying to set a column to True if the text string in the dataframe contains any of the items from the long list.

I've been able to make it work, but the current code is very slow, especially since there are a few (5) of these functions that need to run to set different values.

```
def contains_make(row) :

   matches = ['foo', 'bar', 'etc']

   for m in matches :
       if m in row['field'].lower() :
           return True

   return False

df.loc[df.apply(contains_make, axis=1),'contains_make'] = True
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for doing this faster?

The typical solutions (pd.isin, pd.merge) won't work for me because I'm trying to match to a subset of the string ("is in") rather than equality ("is" or "==").

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary of all possible strings in matches and then you can check in O(1) if a particular string from the column exists or not as dictionaries are implemented as hash tables in python

Comment: I'm not following...won't this still only work if I'm trying to match a whole word, rather than a subset of the string?

Comment: If you are looking for a substring, this may not work. I answered this if you are looking to match a string against another.